# Refer to a directory in your working directory

Tags: macos, directory-structure

I'm working on the Mac Terminal with the program called `QIIME`. However, my question is more related to basic navigating in the terminal.

When I enter a command, and would like to refer to a file that is located in a directory/map inside my current working directory, how do I do this?

For example:

```
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f sequenceA.fastq
```

Now sequenceA is located in a map in my working directory, so I guess I'll have to add arguments before `sequenceA.qual`, or shouldn't I ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your working directory you should be able to access that file with:

```
the_directory_your_file_is_in/sequenceA.qual
```

else, you could use something like:

```
./the_directory_your_file_is_in/sequenceA.qual
```

A point stands for the directory your are currently in.

```
../the-directory-you-are-in/the_directory_your_file_is_in/sequenceA.qual
```

Two points stand for the directory above your current directory.

Comment: Thanks Tobias!
In my case, both the first and second command line you provided worked.
I guess the third didn't work because the_directory_my_file_is_in does not exist in the parent directory (directory above).

Comment: The third goes like: "the directory above" -> "the directory you are currently in" -> "the directory your file is in" -> "your file". Just a useless up and down :)